Efficient linked list design for a C file manager
Context.
I'm making a file manager in C. To display a list of files in the CWD in ncurses, I chose to implement the file list as a singly linked list of the following structs:
typedef struct FileNode {
    char name[256]
    struct FileNode* next;
} FileNode;

I know for certain that the filenames will never exceed 255 characters plus the null terminator. This is standard for ext2, ext3, ext4, BTRFS, XFS, ZFS and exFAT. (I'm not familiar with DOS filesystems, but I'm just targeting UNIX.)
I have to account for the case in which a given file is renamed to a longer name, in which case I would only change the name for that file node and not rebuild the entire linked list. However, if the name is changed, then the struct will also potentially change places in the list because the list is in alphabetical order of FileNode names.
Note. I will likely add members to the FileNode struct later on to determine which files in the list are selected by the user in the ncurses interface, for example.
Problem.
Because the FileNode struct reserves 256 bytes for the filename, a lot of memory will be wasted for directories having an enormous number of files with relatively short names. My file manager is general-purpose, so I can well imagine a scenario in which this would occur.
What would an advanced programmer do in this case? Dynamic allocation of filenames would cause significantly more overhead when creating a large file list or when renaming many files simultaneously. (This will be a feature of my file manager.)
Things I've looked into.
After considering FAMs for a while, (see below code snippet) I noticed that things got complicated for file renaming unless I chose to free the node and create a new one upon renaming a file. Is this a good option? The costly part would be to check the length of all the filenames initially in order to generate a list os structs which are individually suited to these lengths. To repeat my earlier question, what would an advanced programmer do?
typedef FileNode {
    struct FileNode* next;
    char name[]; // this member should be the last
} FileNode;


Have you looked at how "professional" file systems handle this?

@ScottHunter I have not, but it's a good idea. What open-source project would you recommend I look at?

I'd first be sure to analyze worst case scenario (max file number) to see if MAX_FILES*256 is really all that much memory.
I'd also do some testing to see if realloc() overhead was actually formidable.  If not, then I'd use strdup() to only allocate enough space as needed for each filename. If more space is needed in the case of changing to a longer filename,  then realloc() as needed and simply live with the execution overhead.
Keep in mind -- renaming to a longer filename should only happen about 50% of the time -- the rest will not need realloc().

@gregspears Thanks for your comment! In that case, you recommend I test whether a given filename is longer than the previous one upon renaming so that I know whether I should use realloc()?

Are you actually running out of memory? Does allocating strings actually cause the program to not meet your performance requirements? A professional programmer would not optimize prematurely, but would code it in the easiest to read and maintain way possible, optimizing trouble spots after proper profiling.

@JasonC Ah, yes; Donald Knuth's famous quote. I knew I would disobey him without noticing soon enough, and here I was caught. Thanks for the reminder!

@GPWR Abstract your file list away enough so that if you DO find you need to optimize it later, you can provide a new implementation as a drop in replacement without modifying the code that uses it.

@JasonC I like that; that's what I'll do. I'll use a doubly linked list but make the implementation very modular using helper functions (e.g., fls_insert, fls_rm, lfs_init_list, etc.). If I see that I need optimisation or have a little time to spare, I'll work out Kenzo's fascinating solution.

@GPWR -- absolutely yes -- use strlen() on the new and old filename to ensure more space is needed.  I bet you may be concerned that this adds more overhead and Of course I don't blame you.  Allocating everything to 256 bytes becomes more attractive all the time, rt?

@gregspears I see. Allocating maximum potential memory is indeed building up appeal, lol. I'm just never sure what "a lot of memory" is. It's difficult to choose when I don't know how many files the average user directory will contain, but I'll assume less than a hundred in most cases and optimise later if needed.

@GPWR -- understood.  In my own file manager program, I do a recursive file search "dry run" which takes less than 1 second even on a directory having 20,000 files . . . this is just to get a file count.   Then I allocate enough memory ( one allocation ) to handle that file count - with file attributes, names and all, then do a 2nd recursive search to get all the file data.  Others use a linked list and do a memory allocation with each new file found.  To me, that is too much overhead -- a potential 20,000 calls to malloc().  Nope! -- probably some memory fragmentation that way too. . .

@GPWR -- I realize you might be wondering:  my file structure has 256 bytes for the name, and some more space reserved for the file date, time, size, attribute . . . basically all the findfirst data structure info plus name length . . . a total of about 300 bytes.  So I allocate file_count * 300  . . .  even if file_count == 20,000 files.  Has worked best for me, long time now.  Edit: I also save all the subdirectory names ( and attributes ) as a path string.  It's the only way you can build a visual tree structure for the user.

@gregspears Very cool. Do you then declare a pointer for every 300-byte chunk of your contiguously allocated memory? Because if you add files to your directory, I'm assuming you can't guarantee that your added file nodes will be in contiguous memory as well. I really like the idea of calling malloc() a single time, thanks so much for your advice.

@GPWR - hi.  Here is a link to some live code which compiles in MS Visual C, and tested by me just now.  It is actual program code with junk removed that does not help.  It illustrates the building of a directory list using a single malloc().  In answer to your question, if there is any directory modification I re-build the entire list.  Many reasons ie: sometimes I'm just changing file timestamps or deleting many files at once.  It's much easier to just send a refresh message back to the caller and have the whole list rebuilt.

@gregspears Thank you for sharing a demonstration, that's very useful. Okay, I'll try the approach of rebuilding the whole list with the code I have right now. It sounded redundant at first but not I realise that it may often be much quicker than checking which files were modified and insert them in the list. Thanks a lot.

@GPWR -- very welcome.  Maybe you've noticed by now that it's got a blunder or two -- ie: the printf()  at the end of build_dir_list() lost the %d formatters in an unfortunate last-minute update, and a few of the comments are no longer accurate or meaningful -- cuz like I said this is legacy code I cleanup up quickly to share with you.  I'm very glad I did not submit this code as an official answer, the community would have beat me righteously, lol.  That said, this code is tested and works nicely, and have a great day.

Some ideas from an Algorithms perspective:
For an always sorted list, you could make use of data structures like AVL or Red-Black Trees to maintain sorted order of FileList upon creating, deleting or renaming a file as per your choice.
To improve performance with large directories:
Use a hash table for filename lookups, inspired by the linux kernel's dcache
Map filenames (or file IDs) to FileNode pointers in the Red Black Tree for O(1) lookups.
To handle rename cases, I would:

Retrieve the FileNode pointer using Hash table.
Free the occupied memory by FileNode->name. Delete the node from Red-black tree and rebalance.
Reallocate the necessary memory required.
Copy the newName to FileNode->name. Insert the node in Red-black tree and rebalance again.

Further scope of improvement:

There's a concept called relaxed balancing for RB trees/AVL trees. You can explore the tradeoffs in this article.
For higher degree of concurrent rebalancing: Chromatic binary search trees and HyperRed-Black trees


I had never noticed dcache before. Thank you for the reference, I will look at its implementation. Hash tables are one of my favourite data structures, so I'm glad that I now have a valid excuse to use them. And thank you for giving a concrete rename example, that's super nice.
